# Is pitch key mapping available in any of NI Komplete Ultimate 10 synths?

Tags: synthesizer, synthesis

I played with Sytrus synthesizer recently. It has a cool feature, where you can map pitch offset to particular oscilator for a given key. There is a factory preset named Transchorder.
It has 3 oscillators. It's 2nd oscilator has a pitch mapping to 3 semitone up for some keys and 4 semitone up for others, so in effect it gives a minor or major triad depending on the mapping for the given key (3rd oscilator is 5th above).

Here is a screenshot on how it looks like in the plugin:
[image]

My question is if this kind of feature is available in any of NI Komplete 10 synths? I know that I can achieve it by adding some kind of automation for the pitch for particular oscillator, but having some kind of automated solution will be nice to have.